# send id through the link with php and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have table with items and for each item there is an option for user to delete and restore it. And there is special php file for it 'delete.php'.

```
print "<td>";
if ($row['deleted'] == 'y') {
print "<a href='delete.php?id=2'>Undeleted</a> ";
                     }
if ($row['deleted'] == 'n') {
print "<a href='delete.php?id=1'>Deleted</a> "; //'$_GET['id']'
}
print "</td>"
```

My question is how can I get the id of item that user clicked and send it to 'delete.php'?
So instead of

```
"<a href='delete.php?**id=2**'>Undeleted</a> ";
```

there should be something like:

```
 "<a href='delete.php?**$_GET['id']'**'>Undeleted</a> ";
```

or

```
 "<a href='delete.php?**<?php $_GET['id'] ?>**'>Undeleted</a> ";
```

but in second example it doesn't make sense php inside php. I think I probably just don't know correct syntax.

Comment: just use `{$_GET['id']}`, no need for the extra php tags since it is already inside them.

Answer (score 1):

what's wrong with

```
echo "<a href='delete.php?id=$_GET[id]'>Undeleted</a>";
```

?

or, in somewhat more modern terms:

```
echo <<<EOL
<a href="delete.php?id={$_GET['id']}">Undeleted</a>
EOL;
```

Comment: it doesn't send and id, just empty: example.com/delete.php?id=

Comment: using _GET presumes that you actually have `http://example.com/script.php?id=XXX` in the url...

Comment: and how can I get this id in my 'delete.php' file and use it for my SQL statement?

Comment: you need to build the url properly in whatever script is building this link.

Comment: does it have to be something like:                                    $id = $_GET['id']; 
$sql_update = "UPDATE inventory set deleted = 'y' where id = $id";

Comment: no. because then you're wide open to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Since you even suggest such a thing, I suggest you stop working on this code and read up about the attacks first.

Comment: but what is the syntax to get this id for my SQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send the id to delete.php, just keep your HTML part as it is :

```
print "<td>";
if ($row['deleted'] == 'y') {
   print "<a href='delete.php?id=2'>Undeleted</a> ";
                 }
if ($row['deleted'] == 'n') {
   print "<a href='delete.php?id=1'>Deleted</a> "; //'$_GET['id']'
}
print "</td>"
```

Inside delete.php, Access the id as :

```
 $id = $_GET['id']
```

If you want to tell the delete.php whether to delete or restore the item, you might want to add another param to the URL like delete.php?id=1&action=d or delete.php?id=1&action=u

Now, if your id comes from a GET parameter of the above file like file.php?id=1, you will have to access it like -

```
print "<a href='delete.php?id={$_GET[id]}'>Undeleted</a> ";
```

Make sure that you sanitize and escape this id value before using it in the query.

Comment: but the thing is that print "<a href='delete.php?id=1'>Deleted</a> "; can't be with id = 1 or 2, because there is hundread of items in my table, and when user clicks to delete item 2, than this id have to go to my sql statement and update this item.